# CKFinder.Connector.ConnectorException when uploading file in ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have taken over an ASP.NET MVC3 project which incorporates ckfinder with ckeditor. This application has been in production for several years and has been fully functional.

It was migrated to a new server and now I am receiving the following exception when attempting to upload a file using ckfinder:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Exception of type 'CKFinder.Connector.ConnectorException' was thrown.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: CKFinder.Connector.ConnectorException: Exception of
>   type 'CKFinder.Connector.ConnectorException' was thrown.
>
> Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ConnectorException: Exception of type
>   'CKFinder.Connector.ConnectorException' was thrown.]
>   CKFinder.Connector.Connector.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +1378
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +772
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248

I am able to browse the server using ckfinder and add a link to an existing file, rename, and delete files, however, I get this exception when trying to upload a new file.
The config.ascx file is configured correctly and I have granted full permissions to Everyone on all related directories. I have googled this exception and there is very little information about it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

After digging, I was able to find the following xml response:

```
<Connector resourceType="Files"><Error number="12"/></Connector>
```

Using fiddler, I was able to get the full request:

```
 /scripts/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&CKEditor=EventText&CKEditorFuncNum=2&langCode=en HTTP/1.1
```

Here we can see that type=Files is added to the querystring. Reading the config.ascx comments, I saw that this querystring param selects the Resource Type. My resource types included UserFiles, Images, and Flash, but no Files.

I renamed the UserFiles resource type to Files and everything is now working as expected.